# Angular CLI , is running slow (all ng commands)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
System :
Windows 10 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.59 GHz
RAM 16,0 GB
```

```
Angular CLI: 15.0.1
Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.1.2
OS: win32 x64
```

```
Angular: 15.0.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1500.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.0.1
@angular-devkit/core            15.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.0.1
@schematics/angular             15.0.1
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Hi , I make this request because since I installed the angular command line on this computer I have some perfomance problems.
In a nutshell there seems to be a delay in the execution of all ng commands (ex: ng serve, ng version...) that I launch .

In activity manager when I launch these commands the cpu goes up to even 100% but the memory is always around 60/70%

example issue :

```
C:\Users\user\work\angular-test>ng serve
| 
 20/30 seconds ->
⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
10/15 seconds ->
build
```

```
another example with a nonexistent ng command :
C:\Users\user\work\angular-test\>ng koala
|
20 seconds ->
Error: Unknown argument: koala
```

I don't know what could be the problem, I have already tried also uninstalling, reinstalling node.js and angular cli and deleted the cache.

I used 3 different command lines (windows powershell, git bash, vscode terminal)

Comment: In dependance of how large your project is. How much data is already usend on the PC ant etc. the performance can variate. Here you are URL with a discussion about: https://www.reddit.com/r/angular/comments/tknyke/how_much_ram_is_required_for_angular_10_i_am/

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am doing some tests on a new empty project so nothing very heavy , 
but the slowdown happens as I said for all ng commands , so even with ng new project the delay to launch the command is always those 10/20 second. and I really have no idea what the problem might be, I haven't encountered the problem on other PCs with the same or similar system

Comment: Yes. As you said the problem doesn't exists on other PCs. This definetly indictes the problem is about the current PC itself.

Comment: ok thank you then I take it for granted that it is a machine related problem